# microsofts emotions-preview "message": "Video processing failed."

Tags: video, face-detection, azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to get the videos from my dropbox analyzed but even after getting the 202 success, status is showing "video processing failed".

TO crosscheck, I did analysis from other's account. Surprisingly, the same link [video for analysis](https://www.dropbox.com/home?preview=blog2.mp4) from this account is getting success. I am doing the analysis on the same video from my dropbox shareable link!! but it fails.

Any Help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the solution. had to change the offset dl = 1 in the public url of the video, which automatically downloads the video. Essentially, if you are using any cloud drive, then make sure the link provided downloads directly, rather than preview.